# Strange behaviour on usb network adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb

So, I've just bought a new usb network adapter. I plug it and everything was fine. The problem is that when I turn on my Ubuntu  PC, the network adapter is not powered on. If I unplug and plug it again it works like a charm.

I thought about some motherboard energy saver config or something like that, but my older adapter worked fine.

Comment: Did you check whether the adaptor was compatible with Linux before buying it?

Comment: sure. Indeed it works very well after I unplug and plug it again. @JulianKnight